# Tinymce Prompt before paste to properties or not

Tags: c#, .net, tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins

Is it possible to ask before pasting to retain formats in Tinymce Editor? Few days back i found that demo in which on pasting any content in editor it was asking to retain formats on not. Now i am unable to find that Tinymce demo link. Need your help and assistance.

Comment: The demo you saw was for a commercial plugin called PowerPaste - its not part of the open source / community edition of TinyMCE.

Comment: do you help me with that link?

Comment: You can purchase PowerPaste here: https://store.ephox.com/products/powerpaste/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [paste_preprocess](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:paste_preprocess) setting.
You can use a regular javascript user dialog inside the function.
Depending on the user action you may remove whatever you like from the pasted content.